# Generar "id" en un foreach con dialog modal en Laravel con js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Alguien me puede ayudar con js??
Necesito que al ejecutarse este foreach enlace la variable {{$post->id}} para abrir los diferentes modals de diálogo para cada publicación. ¿Cómo puedo implementar mi variable {{post->id}} en js y generar una "id" para cada publicación?

Todo este código está dentro de otro foreach que lista todas las publicaciones:

```html
<button type="button" id="btn-open-modal">
    Open
</button>

<dialog id="modal">
    <table>
        @foreach ($post->likers as $user)
            <tr>

                <td>
                    <a href="{{ route('profile', ['id' => $user->id]) }}">
                        <img class="rounded-md" style="width:50px; height:50px;" 
                        src="{{ $user->profile_photo_url }}" alt="{{ $user->name }}" />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ route('profile', ['id' => $user->id]) }}">
                        {{$user->name}}
                    </a>
                </td> 
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table> 
    <button id="btn-close-modal" class="btn">
        Close
    </button>
</dialog>

<script>
  const btnOpenModal = document.querySelector("#btn-open-modal");
  const btnCloseModal = document.querySelector("#btn-close-modal");
  const modal = document.querySelector("#modal");

  btnOpenModal.addEventListener("click",()=>{
      modal.showModal();
  })

  btnCloseModal.addEventListener("click",()=>{
      modal.close();
  })

</script>
```

Mi js es muy malo agradecería cualquier ayuda. Gracias

Comment: Estás en [es.so]. Por favor traduce tu pregunta al castellano o terminará cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Ya esta traducido perdona por las molestias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo acerca de lo que queres hacer deberias llamar a la funcion js pasando el id

Dentro del foreach

```
<a href="javascript:funcion_js({{ $user->id] }}">Link</a>
```

Fuera del foreach

```
<script>
    function funcion_js(id){
        alert(id);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: const id = $(this).data('{{$post->id}}');



como llamarias {{$post->id}} aqui abajo:



const btnOpenModal = document.querySelector("#btn-open-modal"+id);




haciendo eso no me funciona, pero si lo hago manual con uno de los id del post ejemplo 12 si me funciona:


const btnOpenModal = document.querySelector("#btn-open-modal"+12);

https://pastebin.com/XCamES43
te dejo el pastebin para que lo leas mejor

Comment: te dejo el pastebin para que lo leas mejor https://pastebin.com/XCamES43

Comment: const btnOpenModal = document.querySelector("#btn-open-modal{{$post->id}}");
Tene en cuenta que php se ejecuta del lado del servidor por lo que cuando renderiza el html el id ya va a estar ahi